# typescript interface using other interface keys

Tags: typescript

I have 2 typescript interfaces:

```
interface IObject1 {
  propOne: string,
  propTwo: string,
  ...
}

interface IObject2 {
  'some.prefix.propOne': string,
  'some.prefix.propTwo': string,
  ...
}
```

Is there a shorter way I can create IObject2 out of IObject1 ?

Comment: Nope string manipulation is not possible on keys at compile time

Comment: See [the relevant issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) in GitHub

Answer (score 0):

just curious how your exact use case would look like, why you want to have the properties with the prefix.

Otherwise you can just use `extends` so for example

```
interface IObject2 extends IObject1 {
     // propOne and propTwo available without redeclaration
}
```

Comment: I'm using an external module that has props which are functions I use inside a module context, but they are flat. 
For example: this['some.prefix.someFunctionName'](). I still wants to preserve some hierarchy so I added prefixes

Comment: hm this sounds really weird and like bad practice. Either keep the original module separated and just call it via public functions or if this is for some reasons not possible stick with the original names. I don't think remapping functions like this is a great idea.
Why do you want to preserve some hierachy?