# How to DRY two similar typescript interfaces with different key names

Tags: typescript

I have the same interface in two different formats, a JSON format where the keys are separated by low dash and a javascript camelCase format:

JSON format:

```
interface MyJsonInterface {
  key_one: string;
  key_two: number;
}

interface MyInterface {
  keyOne: string;
  keyTwo: number;
}
```

I would like to prevent duplications and don't know the right way to do it.
I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743596/typescript-interface-using-other-interface-keys) but the answer was not satisfactory, because I don't want the same keys to be available for both interfaces.

is there a different way?

Comment: I don't understand. What you don t want to duplicate exactly?

Comment: _"I would like to prevent duplications and don't know the right way to do it."_ - this is not really a case of interface duplication, if this was my project I'd keep both interfaces around.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's split this task into smaller sub tasks. First of all you need to write an utility type which will convert `snake_case` to `camelCase`. Let's focus on it.

See this:

```js
type Separator = '_'
type Convert<Str extends string, Acc extends string = ''> =
  // Check if Str mathes the pattern string_string
  (Str extends `${infer Head}${Separator}${infer Tail}`
    // If yes, check whether it is a first call or not, because we don't want to capitalize for part of the string
    ? (Acc extends ''
      // This is a first call, because Acc is empty, hence first part should not be capitalized
      ? Convert<Tail, `${Acc}${Head}`>
      // This is not first call, hence Head should be capitalized
      : Convert<Tail, `${Acc}${Capitalize<Head>}`>)
    // This is the last call, because Str does not match the pattern
    : `${Acc}${Capitalize<Str>}`)
```

Now, we can just iterate through the interface and replace each key with converted:

```js
type Builder<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T as Convert<Prop & string>]: T[Prop]
}

// {
//     oneTwoThreeFourthFiveSixSevenEightNineTen: "hello";
// }
type Result = Builder<{
  one_two_three_fourth_five_six_seven_eight_nine_ten: 'hello'
}>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w23aYN) with full code

Make it vice versa:

```js
type Separator = '_'

type IsChar<Char extends string> = Uppercase<Char> extends Lowercase<Char> ? false : true;

type IsCapitalized<Char extends string> =
  IsChar<Char> extends true
  ? Uppercase<Char> extends Char
  ? true
  : false
  : false

type Replace<Char extends string> =
  IsCapitalized<Char> extends true
  ? `${Separator}${Lowercase<Char>}`
  : Char

type Result2 = Replace<'A'>

type CamelToSnake<
  Str extends string,
  Acc extends string = ''
  > =
  Str extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}` ? CamelToSnake<Rest, `${Acc}${Replace<Char>}`> : Acc

// type Result = "foo_bar_baz"
type Result = CamelToSnake<'fooBarBaz'>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVk4vm)

Comment: Is Str extends  ``${infer Head} ${Separator}${infer Tail}`` using template literal types?

Comment: @wlf yes, it is

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine very interesting. Is it possible to do the reverse? Convert camelCase to snake_case?

Comment: @AndreiTătar made an update

Answer (score 1):

The following would do the trick.

```js
interface MyJsonInterface {
  key_one: string;
  key_two: number;
  key_three_other: number;
  key_four_with_another: number;
}

type PropMapping<T> =
  T extends `${infer ST}_${infer ND}_${infer RD}_${infer TH}`
  ? `${ST}${Capitalize<ND>}${Capitalize<RD>}${Capitalize<TH>}`
  : T extends `${infer ST}_${infer ND}_${infer RD}`
  ? `${ST}${Capitalize<ND>}${Capitalize<RD>}`
  : T extends `${infer ST}_${infer ND}`
  ? `${ST}${Capitalize<ND>}`
  : never

type MyInterface = {
  [K in keyof MyJsonInterface as PropMapping<K>]: MyJsonInterface[K]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the ideas of the intuitive and readable [answer above by @lepsch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432709/3963260), here's a version that handles any amount of lodashs/subscripts.

Caviat: I think, it's up to 1000 lodashs which is the inbuilt tail-recursion depth limit of TypeScript since version 4.5. I tested with 1000 and it worksed. Weirdly enough though, using 1001 lodashs did not result in an error ('possibly infinite recursion depth') but the key just vanished from `MyInterface`.

Here's a link to the corresponding [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8BSBnA9iASXGniWQG8AoZZAawnQH18IAuZbMKUAcwG5qdBozAB3XOxABXALYAjaAJr0mYABZQIEZuuiTZCqEqFMYuKVEajg6xnBC5dUffMWCVVm2sYz7TGbiajAA2uAAmcNhq2IxywXCx8YkJcSnx7HK4uMEQ9sYA9PnIAI5SwFC07CrYHGBwUGC8yNbqyIzNwMHByArIYBYgEGHIoGC4yFIADpPQyAiRKAAUALQAfMgAEhBduADK-TAwAJSCjIxq26FnnFKHLoaUAL6UlGDoM8i7UnKc3CA8AFVwJ0ADLhSJqAA8ABV1gBeZDQ5AQAAekBAYRqAAMACTkUAwWYAx6MPEE2YABUeWOQAH5kADkJIIAA3RTIV7vFBfH5cXgAQRgkCgYIiURh8MRyLREAx2LJIEJUAZJIVSuQVJp9IpTOQgzZRg5bw+AGF8HVQNhRRCJcgETzfgKhdBreLYdL0ZjkAByb105DwYLYFDsLhSCACTkfClQXCTVBwaa8ABKEAQFmwwDZMI9sq9jv+ABpkAB5bg8UBwbqoz01As8O2I4sx3BIbDB4Y1vN1vn-RsAIn7xdT2CkwTAubltT+DYRg-hgkKyE06agmfwyHsCDUgWQAEZ2MAYHrxqExWo5ua4KAhiMQIjBGbwNeQFbwW71l2p4Hg-7F0VdHvTR+ige8kSPEYJ1ESI+guZBAmACsQCracmkWNR7DCHIanUOAJ10ANyk4ZB4jAYURjrXwuiOYttl-AjJk0FlgHMGpNFHcdkEmYIpBqeZJhsKtgAAL1vaEADpBCRL8vTLRDK26ekkXYXFyBHMcwEePETUTQTghEiAJWpJl-zQOBaCaUdNFglAYCIidR15GdanqMAahaC84A4KjuhyMjoGLTDkDCQI0wzLMUHmLpBBbNsO0nL1fX9Ft40TAT-lTVdM2zB1ex4QVhVdKFYWLOSkKrYtVNiiB2yGVVyFymcgUaYIiqMrFKrxRreGa0F32K1ZqXWVhTLoyLdLqfTRM3DFgvGFdwrZOYq2CGLY1SpMMrCtcIshbr-gKl1+olUrywUzryGq2qwnq-bAWBVrjthakLvU8ctPIHSBMmgy9u+etese88JUGrFVheY0UAwIhhVIFAESoGgAG0AGk7xMXBjwwHB8BhkhEBQGCUoTTaeEyxbDJR1YAF12GxvBCGIWACdR6mniAA).

```js
interface MyJsonInterface {
  key_one: string;
  key_two: number;
  key_three_other: number;
  key_four_with_another: number;
  key_with_many_more_lodashs_bla_bla_bla_bla_bla: boolean;
  // quirk: keys starting with _ will be turned into upper case (-> HelloStuff)
  __hello__stuff: number
}

type SubstringUntilLodash<T> = T extends `${infer U}_${infer P}` ? U : never; 
type SubstringAfterLodash<T> = T extends `${infer U}_${infer P}` ? P : never; 
type ContainsLodash<T> = SubstringAfterLodash<T> extends '' ? false : true;

type PropMappingRecursive<T extends string, Original extends string = T, Processed extends string = "", Result extends string = ""> =
  // recursion anchor 1: if no lodash contained in T
  ContainsLodash<T> extends false ? 
  // then return T if it was the original string (handles that the first latter is small), else the previous result plus capitalized T.
  T extends Original ? T : `${Result}${Capitalize<T>}` :
  // Making sure the first substring starts with a small letter, and dorecursive call
  Processed extends '' ? PropMappingRecursive<SubstringAfterLodash<T>, Original, `${Processed}_${SubstringUntilLodash<T>}`, `${SubstringUntilLodash<T>}`> :
  // else capitalize and do recursive call
  PropMappingRecursive<SubstringAfterLodash<T>, Original, `${Processed}_${SubstringUntilLodash<T>}`, `${Result}${Capitalize<SubstringUntilLodash<T>>}`>

type MyInterface = {
  [K in keyof MyJsonInterface as PropMappingRecursive<K>]: MyJsonInterface[K]
}
```

[image]