# Best way to declare string structure with TypesScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, template-literals

Let say I have this JavaScript object:

```
const myObject = {
   id: 'my_id', // Base value that following value's structures will be depended on (always pascal case). 
   upperID: 'MY_ID', // Uppercase of `id`.
   camelID: 'myId', // Camel case of `id`.
}
```

I want to use TypeScript to ensure that `id` is always pascal lower case. The `upperID` and `camelID` has same "value" with different string structure as above. What would be the best way to declare this `myObject` type in TypeScript?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with TypeScript. The best I can think of is a runtime check. Why is this question tagged with template-literals?

Comment: @jabaa Because the closest thing I could find for this approach was [template-literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype) documentation. I guess the reason why I couldn't find the answer to my question is because it's just not possible then..? :(

Comment: @jabaa Someone implemented SQL with typescript string types. This ain't nothing https://github.com/codemix/ts-sql

Comment: [Here](https://catchts.com/transformation-utils) you can find type utilities for creating camel/pascal case properties. Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73432506/how-to-dry-two-similar-typescript-interfaces-with-different-key-names#answer-73432894) you can find related answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upper case one is pretty easy with the provided `Uppercase<T>` utility type.

```
type CasedIds<ID extends string> = {
    id: ID,
    upperID: Uppercase<ID>
}


const myObject: CasedIds<'my_id'> = {
   id: 'my_id',
   upperID: 'MY_ID',
} as const
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgZwgEwJLIQHlQEShAD2AgDsMoFgAnASxIHMA+KAXgG8AoKbqG5ALii4ANFx4BXMJCq5BAVSkQqAY0QRsORhwC+HPcoD2JSlAC2IAPIAjAFYRlwQfCRoMmAOTmA+n3fMWUJw8fIKeID7I7qISijI4oQCyAJpeuFE6UIhQhsbAQA)

---

The camel case one gets tricky. So first you need a type that can do this to a string.

There's probably a few ways to do this. Here's one.

```
type CamelCase<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer Pre}_${infer Letter}${infer Post}`
        ? `${Pre}${Capitalize<Letter>}${CamelCase<Post>}`
        : T

type TestCamel = CamelCase<'abc_def_ghi'> // 'abcDefGhi'
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgWwgG3gZwgHgCpQgD2AgDsATNKNYAJwEtiBzAPigF4AoKLqXAosigAMAJAG96AMwjUoABWoQAvgH0xk6VAAyEYEWqK1xKTNkB7KosGduNgPxQRo+UrHwwtYHGS0AXlm260kwGovBIqHAYmGZUwVY2NgBcPOzsoJA8EFRhKGywiCjoWADkcABGAMbKpBASygwAFrTFLAD0rVCllQAitQDiTcVAA)

Let's walk through this.

This generic type takes a string type as the generic parameter `T`. It then check to see if `T` extends a string of a certain pattern that contains an underscore followed by some characters.

If it does, then infer some substrings from that pattern. Infer the part before the underscore as `Pre`, the character after the underscore as `Letter` and the rest of the string as `Post`. Else, just use the string type as is.

Then we can make a new string from the `Pre` the `Letter` capitalized, and the `Post`. But there maybe more underscores, so we do the whole thing again on `Post`. This is a recursive type that stops recursing when there are no underscores left.

---

Using that the rest is easy:

```
type CamelCase<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer Pre}_${infer Letter}${infer Post}`
        ? `${Pre}${Capitalize<Letter>}${CamelCase<Post>}`
        : T

type CasedIds<ID extends string> = {
    id: ID,
    upperID: Uppercase<ID>
    camelID: CamelCase<ID>
}


const myObject: CasedIds<'my_id'> = {
   id: 'my_id',
   upperID: 'MY_ID',
   camelID: 'myId',
} as const
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgWwgG3gZwgHgCpQgD2AgDsATNKNYAJwEtiBzAPigF4AoKLqXAosigAMAJAG96AMwjUoABWoQAvgH0xk6VAAyEYEWqK1xKTNkB7KosGduNgPxQRo+UrHwwtYHGS0AXlm260kwGovBIqHAYmGZUwVY2NgBcPOzsoJCwkRCkAJLkmDkAIniEJOSUNPTMbFAAShBwpKbEyCCYotZctKTJRQA0nVAArmCQ1EXJAKqj0gDGWQWFTIPz4ROZ4ehYRcuKy6mzzVRQCCAA8gBGAFYQs8DJW7n5AOSnyt3PLKxQHdzdya8QO9SM8BtwRmN1s8ALIATWURVBnVWKChpzySMUUEiUEOxCo7CAA)

---

Although you'll probably want a function build these for you:

```
function makeId<T extends string>(id: T): CasedIds<T> {
    return {} as unknown as CasedIds<T> // mock a real implementation
}

const myId = makeId('my_id')
myId.id       // type: 'my_id'
myId.upperID  // type: 'MY_ID'
myId.camelID  // type: 'myId'
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgWwgG3gZwgHgCpQgD2AgDsATNKNYAJwEtiBzAPigF4AoKLqXAosigAMAJAG96AMwjUoABWoQAvgH0xk6VAAyEYEWqK1xKTNkB7KosGduNgPxQRo+UrHwwtYHGS0AXlm260kwGovBIqHAYmGZUwVY2NgBcPOzsoJCwkRCkAJLkmDkAIniEJOSUNPTMbFCi1ly0pMlFADT1UACuYJDURckAqt3SAMZZBYVM7aPhfZnh6FhFk4qp7BIdxMPAtKbEUAhwANYQeTgl-OVUdIxMABSNydgAlMkLufnYLHU2CsAd1HtRIooJFOsRDsRTAB3Pagt55NA4FgAemR+1Mw0OIKgCi8UFoCDAyAgSGInm2u3YK3Yw12VH2IDyNQOxzytwA5AgQMpGuynuwuXkAHSNdio7gAPVsqUFpCFXR6RTFaK4UpljLl0xQSvFqulQA)

Comment: Code golfing tip: use `null!` instead of `{} as ...`.

Comment: Also, if you happen to run into performance issues (if for whatever reason you have super long strings being used here), you might want to consider using TCO types.

Comment: I'd actually use `declare` and avoid the implementation altogether but I find that confuses people who aren't familiar with it.